# "Многие психологи убеждены, что.." - разряд местоимения "многие"

Tags: егэ, местоимения

Из Яндекс-ЕГЭ, вариант 5, [вопрос A11](https://ege.yandex.ru/russian/question/A11/5/):

> **Многие** психологи убеждены, что если избавить человека от внешних и внутренних барьеров, от страхов и стереотипов, то в нем проявится творческое начало.

Я нашел, что **многие** - это местоимение-прилагательное. Но это по соотношению с другими частями речи. А по значению и грамматическим особенностям у него какой разряд? Определительное местоимение, как "сам, самый, весь, всякий" и т.п.?

---

P.S. Если "**многие**" - определительное местоимение, то неясно, каким местоимением является "**сам**", ведь по заданию в указанных предложениях должно быть только *одно* определительное местоимение.

> Да и **сам** человек часто боится собственных неожиданных, нестандартных решений, поскольку они всегда связаны с риском ошибиться и оказаться предметом насмешек окружающих.

Comment: В вашем примере определительное местоимение  в этом предложении: Но жизнь складывается так, что по-настоящему развить способность к творчеству удается ***немногим***.

Comment: @Серж - а как же "**сам**, (самый, весь, всякий, каждый, иной, любой, другой)"? "**Сам**" не будет определительным в "да и **сам** человек"?

Comment: Но и **многие*** тоже определительное местоимение. Психологи - какие? - многие. Здесь "многие" выполняет роль определения.

Comment: @Серж - хм.. возможно, это задание - ошибочное, раз можно выбрать два варианта (и даже три). Дорешаю этот 5-й вариант Яндекс-ЕГЭ и узнаю, какой у них вариант правильный. (0:

Comment: В ответах - один вариант. Но я уточню.

Comment: Сам - определительное местоимение.

Comment: Я же сказал: в ответах - 1 вариант. Тот, который я привел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Многие психологи.

В словарях нет информации о принадлежности слова "многий" к какой-либо части речи, но я бы отнесла его к **неопределенным местоимениям** по следующим причинам.

1) Из толкового словаря: МНОГИЙ,  1. только мн.:  **Составляющие неопределённо большое число**, значительную часть кого-, чего-л. Многие студенты не посещают лекций. Среди многих девушек выделить одну. Многие растения цветут летом. * Чтоб чины добыть, есть многие каналы (Грибоедов). 2. Книжн. Большой, значительный (по количеству). Добыть что-л. многими усилиями. Победа досталась многой кровью.

2) Из грамматики: неопределенные местоимения указывают на **неопределенный** предмет, признак, **количество**.

В то же время в сочетании "многие усилия" (значительные усилия) "многие" по значению ближе к прилагательному.

Answer (score 2):

Цитата:

г) При обозначении значительного количества, неопределённо большого используются **неопределённые** местоимения ***немало, много, многие***.

***Многие*** - это значительное количество из ряда однородных предметов, лиц и прочих единиц:

[Русская грамматика  с участием русских авторов, изд-во Барселонского университета](https://books.google.ru/books?id=62ax50PTdsIC&pg=PA65&lpg=PA65&dq=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5+%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=Sih1VFyicW&sig=dbhWyzeS6Di1Atp5fHZPuoPY3Ok&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5&f=false)

Страницей ранее приводится более конкретная трактовка (с позиции общего заголовка "Выражение количества"): **неопределённые местоименные числительные**.

Comment: Многие - может быть неопределенном местоимением, если выступает в роли существительного. Ср. Многие не любят этот фильм. Но: Многие психологи убеждены.. Психологи - какие? - многие. Здесь "многие" выполняет роль определения. Поэтому относится к разряду определительного местоимения.

Comment: Странно, что русские словари не спешат относить "многие" к какому-либо разряду. По грамматике это местоименное прилагательное, так как имеет соответствующую грамматическую форму. К примеру, местоименное прилагательное какой-то относится к разряду неопределенных местоимений.

Comment: Серж, в предложении это слово может играть роль определения (отвечая на вопрос "какой?"), но как часть речи отнести его, на мой взгляд, логичнее к (местоименным) числительным, чем к прилагательным: оно выражает не собственные свойства сущностей, о которых говорится, а их принадлежность к большим или меньшим группам неопределённого размера (некоторые, многие - из всего, что можно себе представить и т.п.).

Comment: Александр, указанная Вами классификация тоже есть.

Answer (score 1):

Местоимение многие относят к разряду определительных,т.к. оно указывают на признак предмета.

[Русский язык для школьников 6 класс.](http://ucheba-legko.ru/education/russkiy_yazik/6_klass/morfologiya/mestoimenie/lecture_opredelitelnyie_mestoimeniya.html)

- ### ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Ответ ГРАММЫ.РУ>
Разные учебники русского языка по-разному классифицируют местоимения и
наречия, это для Вас не секрет. Поэтому мы будем говорить о конкретном
случае - Вашем примере.
Правильный ответ: сам. Это определительное местоимение. "Немногие" в
первом предложении - существительное (субстантивированное слово: удается
развить(кому?) немногим). "Многие психологи..." - "многие" это не
местоимение, а прилагательное. При определении части речи мы исходим не
только из морфологических признаков, но и из синтаксической роли (часто
это оказывается определяющим фактором).
Обращаем Ваше внимание еще и на то, что для ЕГЭ используется только
общепринятая классификация (без деления местоимений и наречий на
подтипы). Подробно см.[Gramma.ru](http://gramma.ru/EXM/?id=4.27) [Валгина Н.С.,](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-087.htm)

Цитируем Вас: "Неопределенное местоимение "многие"... Конечно, это не
так: в любом значении слово "многие" не может быть НЕОПРЕДЕЛЕННЫМ
местоимением: "Неопределенные местоимения некто, нечто, некий,
некоторый, несколько Подобные слова выполняют и функции
неопределенно-количественных наименований. См. § 166., кто-то, что-то,
какой-то, чей-то, кое-кто, кое-что, кое-какой, кто-либо, что-либо,
какой-либо, чей-либо, кто-нибудь, что-нибудь, какой-нибудь, чей-нибудь
имеют значение приблизительного указания на предмет или признак"
(Валгина Н.С., Розенталь Д.Э., Фомина М.И. Современный русский язык:
Учебник / Под редакцией Н.С. Валгиной. - 6-е изд., перераб. и доп. -
Москва: Логос, 2002).
4 примера, увы, не нашли.
С уважением GRAMMA.RU

Comment: Да, Вера, вы правы. Многие - могут быть и местоимением существительным и прилагательным.

Comment: Серж, у нас две классификации местоимений (грамматическая и семантическая) . 1) Местоимения указывают на предмет, признак или количество, поэтому выделяются местоименные существительные, прилагательные и числительные. 2) Существует 9 разрядов местоимений, в частности определительные и неопределенные. Определительные местоимения имеют значение обобщения или выделения (сам, весь, всякий, каждый, иной, любой, другой).